# How to add Google Maps on my Google Apps Free acount

Tags: google-maps

I have a Google Apps account, the old free one with 50 licenses. I want to enable Google Maps for my users but I can't find the service in the default apps. Can anyone tell me if it's possible and how to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to your Google Apps Dashboard as an administrator (this link should work: https://admin.google.com/CPanelHome), revert back to classic version and on "Your Google Apps" select "enable more services". Scroll down until you find Google Maps and enable it.

In my case it did the trick.